# Create an autocomplete or dropdown based on json object

Tags: json, autocomplete

I'm passing a Json object from PHP with the funcion json_encode(). The result of this enconding is something like

```
var arrSelectCiudadesJson = [{"C_CIUDAD":"Abra Pampa"},{"C_CIUDAD":"Acassuso"},{"C_CIUDAD":"Acceso Bancalari - Gral. Pacheco"},{"C_CIUDAD":"Acebal"},{"C_CIUDAD":"Achiras"},{"C_CIUDAD":"Achumani - La Paz"},...];
```

I would like to use this object and some others to create dropdonw menus and in specific cases autocomplete input boxes. I tried some examples but I think I'm not looking in the right direction.

Could you give me some places were I can look for tutorial or more information?

Thanks in advance!
V

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [jQuery plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) demo.

Answer (score 0):

My personal favourite is: http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/ for Autocomplete, Comes with lots of options and well documented.

For Dropdown menu's - I would suggest something in jQuery UI.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will give it a try! Fingers crossed.